# Rails checkbox checked updates shipping address while using form object pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a form that I'm trying to allow the user to copy over text from billing to shipping address. Unfortunately at the moment it's automatically saving billing address in the shipping address.

My form looks like the following (albeit truncated for massive amount of fields):

```
=form_for @customer, url: create_customer_path, html: {class: 'new-customer} do |f|
 .row
  .col-md-4
   = f.label :first_name
  .col-md-8
   = f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control', required:true
 .row
  .col-md-4
   = f.label :billing_address1
  .col-md-8
   = f.text_field :billing_address1, class: 'form-control', required:true
 .row
  .col-md-12
   = f.check_box :shipping_is_billing
   = f.label :shipping_is_billing, 'Same as billing address'
 .row
  .col-md-4
   = f.label :shipping_address1
  .col-md-8
   = f.text_field :shipping_address1
```

CustomersController

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @customer = CustomerForm.new
  end

  def create
    @customer = CustomerForm.new(customer_params)
    if @customer.save
      redirect_to customer_success_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def customer_params
    params.require(:customer_form).permit!.tap do |p|
      p[:captcha_response] = params['g-recaptcha-response']
    end
  end

end
```

CustomerForm (truncated for massive fields)

```
class CustomerForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  CUSTOMER_ATTRS = %w[
    first_name
  ].freeze

  ADDRESS_ATTRS = %w[
    address1 address2 city state zip
  ].freeze

  attr_accessor(*CUSTOMER_ATTRS)
  attr_accessor(*ADDRESS_ATTRS.map { |attr| 'billing_' + attr })
  attr_accessor(*ADDRESS_ATTRS.map { |attr| 'shipping_' + attr })
  attr_accessor :confirm_email, :captcha_response, :shipping_is_billing

  validates :first_name, presence: true

  validates :billing_address1, presence: true

  validates :shipping_address1, presence: true, unless: :shipping_is_billing

  def save
    return false unless valid?
    persist!
  end

  private

  def captcha_passes
    captcha = Captcha.new
    return if captcha.valid?(captcha_response)
    errors.add(:captcha_response, 'is invalid')
  end

  def persist!
    customer = Customer.new(attrs_for_customer)
    customer.billing_address = CustomerAddress.new(attrs_for_address('billing_'))
    customer.shipping_address = CustomerAddress.new(
  attrs_for_address(shipping_is_billing ? 'billing_' : 'shipping_')
)
    customer.save!
    customer
  end

  def attrs_for_customer
    Hash[
      CUSTOMER_ATTRS.map { |attr| [attr, send(attr)] }
    ]
  end

  def attrs_for_address(prefix)
    Hash[
      ADDRESS_ATTRS.map { |attr| [attr, send(prefix + attr.to_s)] }
    ]
  end
end
```

JS

```
app.newCustomer = () => {
  function init() {
    let check = document.querySelector('#customer_form_shipping_is_billing')
    check.addEventListener('change', toggledUseBilling)
  }

  let toggledUseBilling = event => {
    shippingFields().forEach(field => {
      if(event.target.checked) {
        field.value = null;
        field.removeAttribute('required');
        field.setAttribute('disabled', true);
      } else {
        field.setAttribute('required', true);
        field.removeAttribute('disabled');
      }
    })
  }

  let shippingFields = () => {
    let selectors = [
      '#customer_form_shipping_address1',
      '#customer_form_shipping_address2',
      '#customer_form_shipping_city',
      '#customer_form_shipping_state',
      '#customer_form_shipping_zip',
    ]
    return document.querySelectorAll(selectors.join(', '));
  }

  return init();
}
```

Under the persist! method I'm using the ternary operator on the checkbox to determine the attributes for the address to be billing/shipping. But it doesn't look like it's actually working. How do I grab from the form the checkbox being marked?

Here are the things I've tried:

- Switched = f.check_box :shipping_is_billing to =check_box_tag :shipping_is_billing. Then I had to update my JS to make sure I was grabbing the right checkbox. This stores the shipping data but when checked the business data isn't being copied.
- Attempted to switch attrs_for_address(shipping_is_billing ? 'billing_' : 'shipping_') to attrs_for_address(shipping_is_billing ? 'shipping_' : 'billing_'). If I use the check_box this will populate the data over to shipping but the checkbox becomes ineffectual.
- Put a form_tag around the check_box_tag but this actually stripped out the check box
- Changed the check_box to check_box_tag, updated my JS to look for the correct ID on the checkbox. Can save the shipping address if typed in but if checking the box it does not apply the billing address and I get prompts that the shipping address can't be blank

Answer (score 0):

Did a binding.pry within the persist! method. Looks like shipping_is_billing is pulling a string which is hitting truthy. Changed to

```
customer.shipping_address = CustomerAddress.new(
  attrs_for_address(shipping_is_billing == "1" ? 'billing_' : 'shipping_')
```